# I have an arff file as input for my python program.How can I fetch only the data part of the arff file?

Tags: python, arff

I have arff file as input and I am using liac-arff to read the arff file. Is there a way I can fetch the data section separately?

Comment: [Here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/liac-arff), they use `arff.load(open(...))` to do so. Does this help?